# JSONAARAY Parsing when dynamic key of object

Tags: json, flutter

I am trying to parse json that has dynamic key values. Here is my json format.
Works with flutter

{
"status": "success",
"data": [
{
"accepted": [
{
"id": 15,
"emp_id": 3,
}
]
},
{
"negotiate": [
{
"id": 15,
"emp_id": 3,
}
]
},
]
}

here accepted and negotiate is dynamic key.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want simply displaying this data in my flutter application . I need array of keys like accepted , negotiate etc.... its dynamic  , and from dynamic key want to getting object like id , emp_id